# javascript AddEventListener `click` works on desktop not on tablet

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, onclick, tablet

the following code works perfect on desktop but not on tablet

`card.querySelector("#img").addEventListener('click', this.zoomIn.bind(this));`

I'm testing it on `Samsung SMT510` although I've enabled the dev tools, don't know how (or if possible) to have a dev-tools console debug and breakpoints

Any ideas for the reasons click doesn't take?

Answer (score 0):

Touch does not count as a click in javascript. Instead, you can do something like this to emulate touch as a click:

```js
function onTap(elem, cb) {
  function onTouchStart(evt) {
    elem.addEventListener("ontouchend", onTouchEnd)
  }

  function onTouchEnd(evt) {
    elem.removeEventListener("ontouchstart", onTouchStart)
    elem.removeEventListener("ontouchend", onTouchEnd)
    cb(evt)
  }
}

// usage: 
const elem = document.querySelector('#card')
onTap(elem, this.zoomIn.bind(this)))
```

```html
<div id='card'></div>
```